# Where are the pieces for the "Jet Gun" In Tranzit

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I want to build the Jet gum again, I did when the game first came out, I can only remember 3 pieces, Located in the tunnel going from the bus depot to diner, another under the power generator, and last one in the cabin in the fog. Where is the last piece?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I found the last piece, at the old World at War map located through the main cornfield

Comment: Well that was fast. You found the last piece 40 seconds after asking the question ;) Good for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Parts:

- Engine = Tunnel between the bus depot and diner
- Gauge = Shack between power plant and the town
- Handbrake = Nacht Der Untoten
- Wires = Near Tombstone in power plant

Note that the descriptions above are the general location.  The parts shift around between 2 to 4 different spots in these locations per game.  Each area is not very large so it shouldn't take too long to see the part.

If the weapon breaks and a piece falls into lava it will go back to its original location.  I believe that in some circumstances (the bus running over a part being one) the part will not return.